# View Model not updating UI when inside constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a feeling that my view isn't being updated because the NotifyPropertyChanged event is firing prior to the UI being constructed but I don't know how to overcome this.

I am not really posting code for analysis because I know that the databindings work. They just fail during the construction of the page.

I am strictly posting it so you can get an idea of what I am talking about.

```
    public Obj1 SelectedObj1
    {
        get { return _SelectedObj1; }
        set { _SelectedObj1 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedObj1"); }
    }

    public Obj2 SelectedObj2
    {
        get { return _SelectedObj2; }
        set { _SelectedObj2= value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedObj2"); }
    }

    public Obj3 SelectedObj3
    {
        get { return _SelectedObj3; }
        set { _SelectedObj3 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedObj3"); }
    }
```

Inside my constructor

```
 public constructor(){
     BuildFakeData();
     SelectedObj1 = observableCollection[0];
     SelectedObj2 = SelectedObj1.obj2s.Count > 0 ? SelectedObj1.obj2s[0] : null;
     SelectedObj3 = SelectedObj2.obj3s.Count > 0 ? SelectedObj2.obj3s[0] : null;
   }
```

My question is, when you are doing MVVM, if you set bound properties in the constructor, say for a DataGrid selected Row, will it populate or is it failing because the XAML isn't built yet?

Here is where the datacontext is created in the view

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:ViewModel x:Key="viewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid 
        DataContext="{StaticResource viewModel}">
```

Here is where I am setting the selected item for the grid

```
 <igWPF:XamDataGrid                    
        ActiveDataItem="{Binding SelectedObj1}"
        DataSource="{Binding observableCollection}"
```

Comment: **Unrelated:** LINQ is your friend. Please remove that unneeded conditional operator and use `SelectObj11.obj2s.FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: @HighCore I actually do that in the production code. I just did it this way to limit any confusion. Thank you though.

Comment: @AnthonyRussell I set properties in the constructor and my view is updated correctly. Do you have any binding errors in the output? Also, when are you setting the `DataContext` for the View

Comment: @lll no binding errors in the output. The view is added as a resource in the App.XAML file and then consumed in XAML in the view

Comment: @AnthonyRussell Show me the code that does that

Comment: You aren't required to use INotifyPropertyChanged for a viewmodel. You only need it if you want to change properties after binding.

Comment: @lll I lied, I declare it as a window resource in the view and then consume it in the view. I don't use the APP Xaml for that at all

Comment: @mikez I am well aware. These properties are to programmatically set the selected rows of data grids. They need to be updated.

Comment: @AnthonyRussell Nothing can be updated before the object has been constructed because bindings cannot have been evaluated yet. Also why wouldn't you set `Window.DataContext` instead of making it a resource?

Comment: @AnthonyRussell Tried reproducing but it sets my bound bindings correctly. Can you show the `XAML` of your binding for the `SelectedRow` of `DataGrid`. It looks like something is wrong there

Comment: @lll I have added it in

Answer (score 0):

If your view doesn’t exist yet when the view model is created, then of course, the view isn’t listening yet when your properties update. However, when the view is then created and the view model is assigned as its data context, then the view will automatically load the values from the view model (its data context).

So, INPC shoulnd’t be an issue there at all. You could create properties without INPC in your example and have it work (since the values are already set in the constructor).